# Bodies gain extra momentum after bouncing

Tags: java, physics, game-physics

I am trying to write a simple Physics simulator. However I am facing issues with how the ball bounces. Even though my RESTITUTION is set to 1, the ball bounces a little extra every time it touches the ground.

The Restitution variable:

```
public static double RESTITUTION=1d;
```

The code for handling bounce:

```
if(Y<c.getRadius()){
  VY=Math.abs(VY)*Utils.RESTITUTION;
  Y=c.getRadius();
  c.getCenter().setY(Y);
  c.getV().setY(VY);
  }
```

All variables use double as data type.
Y is the center of the ball.
VY is Y-component of velocity.

Comment: There's probably some violation of conservation of energy that happens.  One way to sort that out is to add an invariant check to correct that with each time step.

Comment: @duffymo The heat is being taken care of by the fan on the CPU, but the sound must be let out via the loudspeaker. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the lesson, @laune.  8)

Comment: Shouldn't you be reversing the sign of the y-component of velocity?  What about x-components?   I consider it a bad sign that you aren't using a 2D Vector abstraction.

Comment: Since the code is for handling the ball hitting the ground, I have used Math.abs(), it's just a test. getCenter(), getV() calls return a Vector2D object and I am setting the Y component of the Vector2D by using Vector2D#setY() setter method.

Answer (score 1):

If `Y < c.getRadius()` the ball has already entered the ground by `c.getRadius() - Y`, and this is added on the way back up.

I think you should keep Y and just invert the speed, etc.

If you bounce at an angle, you might compute the accurate point of impact and correct by that.

Comment: I think that's the case, but shouldn't the ball bounce lesser everytime? I will try this.

Comment: A reduction of the momentum (by reducing the speed) is quite another matter. But you have 1.0 right now.

Comment: I would recommend that anyone without an undergraduate understanding of physics would be better off using an engine written by some who does, unless their purpose is to learn physics.